# remake of google AI challenge, with genericity

Tags: generics, bots, platform

Some of my friends and me have to developp something that could host games, defined by rules, on which client's bots could face. This is generic because it allows to easily change the game, with an other set of rules.

In order to not begin with nothing, we have to look for things that could look like our project, or part of our project. Except the google challenge, we found nothing. That could be internet guides, books, open source projects...

Maybe my english is not good enough, but I can't find key words which leads me to results. "bots" is not as precise as I would, because it rarely make reference to the kind of bot I'm looking for. "AI" is not important. "generic platform" brings me to existing products for sale.

So do you have any idea of documents and/or key words which could help me?

Comment: Do you want your game ai to be able to learn to naturally increase the dificulty of the game? What kind of parameters do your bots need to respond to and learn from? line of sight, sound, collision, tremor, etc...
Be a bit more specific.

Comment: oh it's strange, my "hello !" doesn't appear, even after an edit

Comment: i don't care about what bots are doing. clients are developping bots. i am developping the platform that host the games

Comment: Sounds like a [General Game Playing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_game_playing) server.